# Get openfire Chat History

Tags: ios, xmpp, openfire, browser-history, nslog

I am unable to get the history from open fire. I am using XMPP Framework

How to get chat history from open fire archive and print the history data in nslog?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Smack API - Read Chat Histroy from Openfire Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635034/smack-api-read-chat-histroy-from-openfire-server)

Comment: Hi Chiristian  I can see all history in server archive file , My question is how to get those details programmatically to list in table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable the option in openfire to get chat history.
Login on openfire, Go to group chat, then go to group chat settings, then go to history settings and then select show entire chat history option.

Comment: I have enabled the show entire chat history option . But My question is in openfire itself can i see the chat History and one to one chat history Where I have to see Please Let me know

Comment: you want to see the chat history in openfire? or in app?

Comment: Add Monitoring Service  in openfire then you will be able to see the message history

Comment: I want to see the history in My app : Tarun Khosla

Comment: I need to add any plugins to see the message History  :  Jaspreet Singh

Answer (score 1):

On Join xmpp group you have to write below code for store message in xmpp core database.

```
storage = [XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage   sharedInstance];
moc = [storage mainThreadManagedObjectContext];
XMPPMessageArchiving *xmppMessageArchivingModule = [[XMPPMessageArchiving alloc] initWithMessageArchivingStorage:storage];
[xmppMessageArchivingModule setClientSideMessageArchivingOnly:YES];
[xmppMessageArchivingModule activate:xmppStream];
[xmppMessageArchivingModule addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

after this when you enter in particular group you have to get history from xmpp core database using below code:-

```
XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage *_xmppMsgStorage = [XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage sharedInstance];
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [_xmppMsgStorage mainThreadManagedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject"                                                   inManagedObjectContext:moc];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];
NSError *error;
NSString *predicateFrmt = @"bareJidStr == %@";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateFrmt, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",GroupName,GROUP_CHAT_DOMAIN]];
request.predicate = predicate;
NSArray *messages = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```